# One Django Channels websocket consumer used across whole site?

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, django-channels

I have a Django project that uses WebSockets and one consumer (`ChatConsumer`) for both the chat and notification portion of the application.

I had `routing.py` set to `url(r"^messages/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)", ChatConsumer)` however because notifications are also dependent on the websocket, they need to be accessed from any page on the site.

The reason is that when a user clicks on the notification, it is marked as `read` using

`socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));`

Right now notifications only work when a user is on the `/messages/<username>/` URL.

If I change `routing.py` to account for the whole site, (`url(r"^", ChatConsumer)`), I obviously get a problem

```
File "./consumers.py" in websocket_connect
    other_user = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['username']
  'username'
```

Is there a simple way of resolving this? Because correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think writing a new consumer is appropriate since the notifications and chat are deeply intertwined?

consumers.py

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):

        other_user = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['username']
        me = self.scope['user']
        thread_obj = await self.get_thread(me, other_user)
        self.thread_obj = thread_obj
        chat_room = f"thread_{thread_obj.id}"
        self.chat_room = chat_room
        # below creates the chatroom
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            chat_room,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept"
        })

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        # when a message is recieved from the websocket
        print("receive", event)

        message_type = json.loads(event.get('text','{}')).get('type')
        if message_type == "notification_read":
            user = self.scope['user']
            username = user.username if user.is_authenticated else 'default'
            # Update the notification read status flag in Notification model.
            notification = Notification.objects.filter(notification_user=user).update(notification_read=True)
            print("notification read")
            return

        front_text = event.get('text', None)
        if front_text is not None:
            loaded_dict_data = json.loads(front_text)
            msg =  loaded_dict_data.get('message')
            user = self.scope['user']
            username = user.username if user.is_authenticated else 'default'
            notification_id = 'default'
            myResponse = {
                'message': msg,
                'username': username,
                'notification': notification_id,
            }
            print(myResponse)
            await self.create_chat_message(user, msg)
            other_user = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['username']
            other_user = User.objects.get(username=other_user)
            await self.create_notification(other_user, msg)

            # broadcasts the message event to be sent, the group send layer
            # triggers the chat_message function for all of the group (chat_room)
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.chat_room,
                {
                    'type': 'chat_message',
                    'text': json.dumps(myResponse)
                }
            )

    # chat_method is a custom method name that we made
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        # sends the actual message
        await self.send({
                'type': 'websocket.send',
                'text': event['text']
        })

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        # when the socket disconnects
        print('disconnected', event)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_thread(self, user, other_username):
        return Thread.objects.get_or_new(user, other_username)[0]

    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_chat_message(self, me, msg):
        thread_obj = self.thread_obj
        return ChatMessage.objects.create(thread=thread_obj, user=me, message=msg)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_notification(self, other_user, msg):
        last_chat = ChatMessage.objects.latest('id')
        created_notification = Notification.objects.create(notification_user=other_user, notification_chat=last_chat)
        return created_notification
```

base.html

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // $('div[id^="notification-"]')
      $("#notificationLink").click(function() {
        $('span[id^="notification"]').each(function() {
          var username = '{{ request.user.username }}'
          var data = {
            "type": "notification_read",
            "username": username,
          }
          socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    });
  </script>

<script>
...
    var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname
    var socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(endpoint)
    // all the websocket scripts - client side*
...
</script>
```

Comment: hi, i think better to create new `ChatConsumer`  to make your code more readable and minimize of the `if` branches. Right now if some one start to read your code to make some changes for the notifications, need to be read more other text.

Comment: Hmm okay thank you. I'm going to send you a github link with the `consumers.py` via email.

Comment: You need to connect to it from any page in the site which means you should add your JS socket code to the base template so that it connects on the whole site upon loading.

Comment: @Ken4scholars Hey, my JS socket code is on the base.html right now

Comment: @BearBrown hello,  I have the same code as trilla, can you send me the other chatconsumer code to my mail bernardoolisan@gmail.com?

Comment: or @Trilla can you send me the other chatconsumer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should send other_user with message so it should be like that

```
 msg =  loaded_dict_data.get('message')
 other_user =  loaded_dict_data.get('other_user')
```

so you no more need to use self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['username']
BTW can you share the code on github because i prepare to do something like this and i think your project will help me alot

Comment: Hi thank you, I may end up writing another consumer. I got my code from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVH05S1qab8

Comment: yeah i know this tutorial but  this tutorial talking about public chat and what i wanna implement is a private chat so i would be pleasure if u send me the code

Comment: lol things got mixed up with me idk why i thought it was a private chat project :D